# Date returns non-existing day

Tags: ruby

I'd like to iterate over the days in month, so:

```
require 'time'
Time.now.month # => 5
Time.now.day.next # => 32
```

What does this mean? 32nd of May?

Also,

```
rota.rb:2:in `<main>': undefined method `days_in_month' for Time:Class (NoMethodError)
```

What's wrong?

Comment: `What does this mean?` => What did **you** mean?; `What's wrong?` => What's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The `next` call has nothing to do with date or time - `Time.now.day` returns an integer. Calling `next` (or `succ`) returns that number plus one. See [Fixnum](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Fixnum.html) documentation for more info.

Answer (score 1):

This should explain it:

```
Time.now.day.class
=> Fixnum
```

Fixnum doesn't know anything about dates, but it does have a method `next`.

If you want to advance to the next day then:

```
(Time.now + (60 * 60 * 24)).day
=> 1
```

Or if you have Rails installed you can do:

```
require 'active_support/time'
(Time.now + 1.day).day
=> 1
```

Comment: http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.2/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html says there is next method to Date, weird. But ok, any idea why I don't have date_next, days_in_month , any of those methods in Date class?

Comment: [Date](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.2/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html) and [Time](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Time.html) are two different classes. When you call `Time.now` you are getting a `Time` object, not a `Date`, see http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Time.html#method-c-now

Comment: Like @Exupery said, in addition to that `days_in_month` is an `active_support` method. You need the Rails gem and have to `require 'active_support/time'`, then you can do `Time.days_in_month(5)` for example.